# Algorithms question/problem lists

Tags: algorithm

This may not be question of programming and people are open to close.

Does anyone has list of questions/problems to solve which helps to improve algorithms skills
may be for interview purpose.

Comment: buy steve skiena's book, or one of sedgewicks...

Comment: Maybe not exact duplictes, but similar questions have been asked many times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310018/a-common-set-of-problems-to-learn-new-languages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031926/standard-programming-problems-for-learning-a-new-language http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901/interview-programming-test-practice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368/what-is-the-best-interview-question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245800/oop-problems-to-use-for-coding-tests-during-interviews and others

Comment: @Mitch:I'm forced to respectfully disagree -- Sedgewick was/is a fine designer of algorithms. Unfortunately, his writing skills are at least as poor as his design skills are good. Offhand, the only worse author I can think of is Herbert Schildt.

Answer (score 5):

A good option is [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/).

In its own description:

> Project Euler is a series of challenging mathematical/computer programming problems that will require more than just mathematical insights to solve. Although mathematics will help you arrive at elegant and efficient methods, the use of a computer and programming skills will be required to solve most problems.
>
> The motivation for starting Project Euler, and its continuation, is to provide a platform for the inquiring mind to delve into unfamiliar areas and learn new concepts in a fun and recreational context.

This seems like a perfect match...

Comment: agreed that Project euler will sharpen your problem solving and mathematical skills, but will it teach you fundemental comp-sci algorithms? Probably not...

Comment: Yeah - but for sharpening for interviews, its probably not a bad option...

Answer (score 3):

Try [TopCoder](http://www.topcoder.com/tc). They have held hundreds of algorithm competitions. Their archive contains thousands of problems for practice, including editorials describing the solutions. You can also view other people's submitted source code for the problems.

This will certainly sharpen your algorithm and problem solving skills, which should make you better prepared for algorithmic interview questions.

Answer (score 0):

[Fizz-Buzz](http://imranontech.com/2007/01/24/using-fizzbuzz-to-find-developers-who-grok-coding/)?